# Unable to use REST resource from app - 415 response is not in JSON format

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, rest, jira

I am attempting to use the following REST resource from a standalone OpenSocial (Atlassian Jira) gadget.

I can query the resource through the browser using the following URL:

https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9

I can issue the same request from my dev machine. It certainly looks like JSON to me... However, when I query from my gadget, I get

```
GET 10.0.15.10:2990/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/CRD-1  415 Unsupported Media Type (32ms)
```

The response is being returned as HTML. This is the response body from tomcat:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.20 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 415 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.20</h3></body></html>
```

Here is my AJAX call (It is essentially JQuery wrapped in the [Atlassian gadget JavaScript Framework](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/Using+the+Atlassian+Gadgets+JavaScript+Framework)):

```
 args: [{
         key: "issueData",
         ajaxOptions: function() {
             return {
                 url: "/rest/api/latest/issue/CRDTRK-1"
             };
         }
  }]
```

I've tried adding `dataType: "json"` to the ajax request but to no avail. I'm probably missing something simple.

Here are the request/response headers:

```
Response Headers
Content-Length  1051
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Sun, 10 Jun 2012 15:53:06 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-AREQUESTID    1013x5993x1
X-ASESSIONID    1bi5et0
X-AUSERNAME admin
X-Seraph-LoginReason    OK

Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie  atlassian.xsrf.token=BP8Q-WXN6-SKX3-    
DNT 1
Host    10.0.15.10:2990
Referer http://10.0.15.10:2990/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: It looks like a 415 is an issue with the local machine... take a look here. http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E415.html

Comment: I can query other rest resources from my app, so can't see how it can be related to my local machine. I will post the request/response headers from firebug...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your gadget specification file needs to have the contentType request headers sent in your ajax options:

```
args: [{
    key: "issueData",
    ajaxOptions: function() {
        return {
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "/rest/api/2.0.alpha1/issue/CRDTRK-1"
        };
    },
}]
```

Check the request header in your HTTP request. 
Should be: `Content-Type: application/json`
Instead of: `Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

try to use getJSON and out callBack=?
as where:

```
$.getJSON('https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9jsoncallback=?', function(data){ $.each(data, function(){ alert(this.expand); }); });
```

Comment: Thanks, but still having problems... Since I am querying my local instance of Jira my query looks like this:
jQuery.getJSON('/rest/api/latest/issue/CRDTRK-1?jsoncallback=?', function(data){ $.each(data, function(){ AJS.$("<p>").append(this.expand); });
But now I get this error: "missing : after property id" any ideas?

Comment: can you get result at browser like json result

Comment: Yes. When accessing the REST URL from the browser, the page is transferred as content-type: application/json, yet when I access the same resource through an ajax request it is being transferred as text/html. Is there a way to force the response to return as json?

Comment: in documentation of your api must explain how u can use a response as json check http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

Comment: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs#JIRARESTAPIs-BrowsingandTestingyourRESTAPIsfromtheApplicationUI